# how do I run a java .jar in Matlab

Tags: java, matlab, jar

I need to run a Java .jar file in Matlab.

Let's call the file MyJar.jar, I am running Java 1.8.0_121-b13 if that helps.

I have tried different solutions, and received these corresponding errors

```
java -jar MyJar.jar % Solution 1 Error: Attempt to execute SCRIPT java as a function: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017b\toolbox\matlab\general\java.m
import MyJar        % Solution 2 Error: Import argument 'MyJar' cannot be found or cannot be imported.
```

I have setup the javaclasspath: C:\My\Java\Class\Path\To\MyJar.jar (Even though it didn't help anything)

```
javaclasspath('C:\My\Java\Class\Path\To\MyJar.jar')
```

I am even prepared to edit the classpath.txt file, (although, if that is the solution I would like a walk through cuz that is beyond my understanding and I don't want to mess things up.)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

****Working Solution (thanks to m3tho; see their comments for explanation)

```
system ('java -jar C:\My\Java\Class\Path\To\MyJar.jar')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution I can think of is to execute the jar in a system command with:

```
system('java -jar MyJar.jar')
```

This way should work on any OS without any workaround.

Comment: Thank you for you help but that gives me an "Error: Unable to access jarfile MyJar.jar" message

Comment: You should specify the fullpath of the jar file or change the matlab path in the parent folder where the jar can be found.

Comment: I have used both javaclasspath and javaaddpath with the full path; they seem to work. However is there a way to check?

Comment: Have you tried `system('java -jar C:\My\Java\Class\Path\To\MyJar.jar')`? It should work without setting javaclasspath.

Comment: It worked because in MATLAB the command system runs cmd (or bash, etc.) in MATLAB's current folder that was different from `C:\My\Java\Class\Path\To\`