# still stuck with running a .jar in MATLAB

Tags: java, matlab, jar

I need to run a .jar in MATLAB, exactly as described in this original question I found in my search of Stack Overflow: [how do I run a java .jar in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47160742/how-do-i-run-a-java-jar-in-matlab) I was having the same issues as the user here (got the same errors, did the same troubleshooting) The only difference is that I am running Java 1.8.0_144-b01 vs Java 1.8.0_121-b13 in the linked example.

However, when I tried the solution that worked in the above situation...

`system ('java -jar C:\My\Java\Class\Path\To\MyJar.jar')`

...I got the following message: "'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
operable program or batch file. "

The .jar is in my static path. The current directory is set to where the .jar file is located. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems you don't have a `java` program on your system's `PATH`. Do you have a Java runtime installed? Maybe you need to specify the path to it: `system ('"C:\Program Files\...\java" -jar C:\My\Java\Class\Path\To\MyJar.jar')`.

Comment: Derp! That totally worked. I just assumed that java would be installed on this computer, but apparently not. Thank you!